# How do I update phpMyAdmin on EC2 LAMP Server?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, lamp

I have a LAMP server on an EC2 instance. I downloaded phpMyAdmin using Amazon's guide here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html.

On the phpMyAdmin page it says that:
"A newer version of phpMyAdmin is available and you should consider upgrading. The newest version is 4.6.5.2, released on 2016-12-05."
and I need to update it and also MySQL to use new features they put on the updates.

I'm accessing the EC2 instance from the terminal in my Mac laptop. I've tried a lot of things but I couldn't manage it. I've tried

```
sudo yum install -y phpMyAdmin
sudo yum install
```

I tried to manually download the latest version from phpmyadmin.net and change the files in the folder but I couldn't access the phpmyadmin folder in the first place.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the version of phpMyAdmin maintained by your distribution (presumably Fedora, CentOS, or Red Hat); this means that basically you're not responsible for (or able to) upgrade the software that's under control of the package manager (aside from running the updates occasionally). If you wish to use a different version, you're certainly able to remove the package manager version then [install it manually](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install). I don't use EPEL, but I believe the highest version currently distributed is 4.4.15.9 ([reference](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/p/), which I think is because of the older versions of PHP and/or MySQL which are currently shipped. So you might not be able to upgrade due to your MySQL or PHP versions, but YMMV.

Basically, if you're using the package managed version, the whole point is so you don't have to worry about manual updates.

You can disable the notification by adding the directive `$cfg['VersionCheck'] = false;` to your `config.inc.php` (which may be in `/etc/` or `/etc/phpmyadmin`, but I'm just guessing about how your distribution may handle it.).

Comment: or, if that doesn't suit you, ditch the distribution version of phpmyadmin and run an upstream.  phpmyadmin has almost no configuration, it's hard to go wrong.   Just don't leave it open to the world, as folks will be looking for it.  May I recommend considering running something like this, just when you need it ? https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/